# Fitting different models to my data in R

Tags: r, fitting, lognormal-distribution, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution

I have number of seeds fallen at different distances. I need to know which model fits these data, if any model does. There are different models that have been used to fit these data: negative exponential, Weibull, lognormal. I need to know how to fit all of them in R, starting from 0, generating the data. I only managed to fit the model 2-parameter asymptotic exponential, but I didn't know which parameter to look at, or generate, to know if it was a good fit.

The data directly from my Excel is this:

```
Distancia (distance)
 5.4 9.69 11.32 12.84 12.98 14.92 17.76 17.94 17.96 22.17 
    61.37 63.18 87.88 94.24 112.02 116.91 45.23 141.2

Abundancia (number)
1 2 9 49 24 0 18 3 5 3 10 0 3 0 7 9 6 3
```

Comment: There's really no significant evidence that the abundance varies significantly with distance!  Because most of the data are obtained at close distances, you should *expect* both the largest abundance (and the smallest!) to be at short distances: which they are.  The presence of the outlying large abundance at a short distance, although it creates the *appearance* of a trend, therefore could be entirely accidental. Visualize this in `R` with a plot like `plot(d, sqrt(a), cex=(1 + sqrt(a))/3, pch=19)` where `d` is the [Distancia] vector and `a` is the [Abundancia] vector.

Comment: @whuber - nice plot. Given the anticipation of an exponential trend, a plot against `log(d)` seems more appropriate. It doesn't add all that much but perhaps even more clearly disabuses us of any notion of downward trend.

Comment: Further to all that is here, the Kendall and Spearman correlations are very close to 0, and have p-values around 0.7 (though ties in the counts interfere there); there's really nothing to suggest there's any overall increasing or decreasing relationship.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @whuber's comment, consider the following plot:

[image]

One of the above plots is your data from above, the other 8 are the same data, but the order has been randomized (separately for distance and abundance) representing a null hypotheses of no relationship.  Can you tell which one is your original data? (no fair plotting the data in another window and comparing).  If you cannot tell which is the real data, then that is consistent with a null hypothesis of no relationship.

More details on this idea are in:

> ```
>  Buja, A., Cook, D. Hofmann, H., Lawrence, M. Lee, E.-K., Swayne,
>  D.F and Wickham, H. (2009) Statistical Inference for exploratory
>  data analysis and model diagnostics Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A 2009
>  367, 4361-4383 doi: 10.1098/rsta.2009.0120
> ```

and this plot was created using the `vis.test` and `vt.scatterpermute` functions from the TeachingDemos package in R.

Comment: Peter Huber (so far as I know not related to our leader) nicely compares this procedure to a police line-up mixing a suspect and arbitrary others. See http://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Learned-Probability-Statistics/dp/1118010647

Comment: Great plot. I have referred people to that same paper myself, it deserves to be more widely known.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. It's what i suspected, but my tutor insists the relationship is very clear. If it's not to difficult could you tell me how to try to fit the model?, even if they don't fit, it's good to have the "proof" and because i have another set of data that I think might be correlated. (it has a significant Spearman's correlation)

Comment: @Valentina, I would not fit a normal based regression model, your y-values are clearly skewed and you sample size is small enough that this will matter.  You could fit a generalized linear model (glm) with the response following either a poisson or gamma distribution, but make sure that you know what assumptions you are making and if they are reasonable.  if you are not familiar with glm's then you will need more study than can really be included in a forum like this.  Quantile regression may be another approach of interest.

Comment: Thank you Greg Snow.. I do know what a Generalized linear and nonlinear model is, i've been using Poisson for my previous (and no very useful) analysis. I just can't make them work in R. Because i know nothing of computers, the language is difficult for me. That's what i need help with.

Comment: @Valentina, Look at the help page for `glm` in R, the first example is a Poisson Regression.  Another resource (among many) is the HSAUR package.  This package is support for a book (the book itself is recommended), but when you install the package you get all the examples from the book as well.  There is a chapter on glm, it focuses more on logistic regression, but there is some on Poisson regression as well and from the running the code side, what applies to logistic is pretty much the same for Poisson.